# CSV oscillating data, simple peak find with excel

Tags: excel, csv

Goal: Find the peak values(v,t) of sensor data from a compound pendulum.

The sensor used provides 1024 pulses of data per second. The tests take anywhere from 15 seconds to 1 minute, so a lot of lines are written to a file. I have one open in excel that is 48000 lines. When plotted this produces a damped oscillating graph going through 0 (there is +v and -v). I would like to find the peak values(v,t) automatically and have them written right under eachother

All the data is in two columns, time on the left and speed on the right. Sometimes there are long peaks, the max speed stays the same for several rows before dropping again. I would like the absolute peak, so the mean of the time. [Capture from excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aClL8.png).

I have tried:

In the cells to the right

=IF(AA6<=AA5;1;0)

And the cells to the right of that

=IF((OR(AND(AB5=1;AB6=0);AND(AB5=0;AB6=1)));1;0)

The idea here is that it produces a 0 or 1. When both cells are 1 then that should be the peak, but that doesn't work because of the speed staying the same for a while at the peaks.

Is there an easy way to do this in Excel, or should other methods be considered (VBA)?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your quick answer.

I did end up doing it in VBA, but not with your method. I used basic logic which works just fine for my application of the data. The code might not be optimal, but I am fairly content.

Here is the code:

Private Sub peak_find()

```
Dim j, k  As Integer
Dim t As Double

j = 0



    Do While Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value)

            If ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value Then

                k = 0


                Do While ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(k, 0).Value

                    k = k + 1

                Loop




                If ActiveCell.Value > ActiveCell.Offset(k, 0).Value And ActiveCell.Value > ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value And ActiveCell.Value > 0 Then


                    k = k - 1
                    Range("E1").Offset(j, 0).Value = ActiveCell.Value

                    t = (ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value + ActiveCell.Offset(k, -1)) / 2

                    Range("D1").Offset(j, 0).Value = t

                    j = j + 1


                ElseIf ActiveCell.Value < ActiveCell.Offset(k, 0).Value And ActiveCell.Value < ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value And ActiveCell.Value < 0 Then


                    k = k - 1

                    Range("G1").Offset(j, 0).Value = ActiveCell.Value

                    t = (ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value + ActiveCell.Offset(k, -1).Value) / 2

                    Range("F1").Offset(j, 0).Value = t


                ElseIf ActiveCell.Value > ActiveCell.Offset(k, 0).Value And ActiveCell.Value < ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value Then


            End If


        ElseIf ActiveCell.Value > ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value And ActiveCell.Value > ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value Then


            Range("E1").Offset(j, 0).Value = ActiveCell.Value
            Range("D1").Offset(j, 0).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value


            j = j + 1


        ElseIf ActiveCell.Value < ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value And ActiveCell.Value < ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value Then


            Range("G1").Offset(j, 0).Value = ActiveCell.Value
            Range("F1").Offset(j, 0).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value




        End If


        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate




    Loop

    Range("D1").Activate
```

End Sub

It might be faster if I avoid working with active cells, but I'll work on that later. It is saving me a lot of time as is.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you will have several MAXes and Mins, you cannot do it with simple spreadsheet formulae. You need to do some VBA to:

1. Calculate the frequency/period,
2. Use the result to set the size of the range within which you look for a max/min,
3. Scan your data to find the maxs and mins.

Best would be to implement a Ki-Square fitting, extract the frequency and phase, and use the resulting parameters to feed a function that would give you the max and mins.